# Could not change transaction status (0) (SQLSetConnectAttr)

Tags: sql-server, django, pyodbc, freetds

We have a Django app connected to a remote SQL-server database.
I get an error when i try to do an update request on a database table :
`[HY000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Could not change transaction status (0) (SQLSetConnectAttr).`
I conclude that a similar request is still in progress and it blocks all my requests.
1/ The "autocommit" parameter is True.
2/ I tested :
`connection.rollback()`
This did not resolve the problem.
3/ I tried to do a live SQL query on the database.
My query returns no error.
It's a problem with Django or the libraries used.

Traceback :
/venv/src/django-pyodbc-azure/sql_server/pyodbc/base.pyc in
_set_autocommit(self, autocommit)
361         else:
362             self.connection.rollback()
--> 363         self.connection.autocommit = autocommit
364 
365     def check_constraints(self, table_names=None):

Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Could not change 
transaction status (0) (SQLSetConnectAttr)')

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: Do you do update/insert?

Comment: No, I can't update and I can't create via Django's ORM. But the problem on these two actions (update, create) did not start at the same time.

Comment: I use django-extensions in my app. When I use "python manage.py shell_plus", i can update or create. If I use "django manage.py shell" or create/update via my app, the error is returned.

Comment: I changed commit and I don't have this error anymore. So the latest changes to my code are causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed.
I remove the following line:

```
if not ModelName.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk)
```

My code :

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=ModelName)
def model_name_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not ModelName.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk):
        instance.field_name = value
```